# Display Item in an overlay style In VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I want display something like following image using Graphics. Can you please tell me how can I do this.? Graphic Item should has overlay. If I use simple DrawRectangle then it will not look good.[image]

Thanks

Comment: what will you use - wpf, winforms, webforms, silverlight,... ? Or do you just want to draw this to a image using GDI+?

Comment: I am using windows forms

Comment: then this will be a bit harder - you have to use GDI to draw the primitves (maybe into a custom control) - it's not terrible hard to do but there is some work involved - maybe you find some code on the net?